# Windows CE 6.0 app not starting

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5, wce

I am porting an Win CE 6.0 app to a new hardware.

The app doesn't start on both WIN CE 6.0 and WEC 7 on the new hardware.

But if you first re-install the NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab over the existing installation (force installation) then run the app, it starts both on WIN CE 6.0 and WEC 7

Every time after a reboot the NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab needs to be re-installed to start the app.

I can also debug the app from VSTD 2008 which actually gave me the clue to deploy the NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab at the very beginning.

Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: What does NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab cab file do? I mean, does it update/copy any dll/exe? does it change the registry?

Comment: Found the solution. The NetCF framework was not a part of the OS image and had to be installed later. It it were there would be no problem.

Comment: Great! Please add that as answer and mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The NetCF framework was not a part of the OS image and had to be installed later. If it were there would be no problem.